# how can I count mysql data with group by

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I have a php web page and I got a problem with counting data using group by in mysql query

When any question submitted, id is automatically add and idqu=0
if question replied then idqu is equal to replied question's id

My table and data

```
id idqu question answer    user    date

1   0   quest1             test    28042014

2   0   quest2             scott   29042014

3   2   reply1             andy    01052014

4   0   quest3             test    01052014

5   4   reply2             scot    01052014
```

My question is how can I count question's reply?

```
quest1 (0)

quest2 (1)

quest3 (1)
```

Comment: This will surely help => http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_count.php --- no better way to learn, than to "learn" ;-) ***"Teach a man how to fish..."***

Comment: I would suggest normalizing your data just a little bit. Creating a `question` table and a corresponding `answer` table would make manging this data much easier for you. You can create a foreign key to map the rows in the answer table to the appropriate question table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does the job. I gave the table the name "`tbl`"

```
Select q.id, count(a.id) as answers

From tbl q

Left join tbl a on a.idqu=q.id

Where q.idqu=0

Group by q.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Select t1.question, count(t2.id) as counts
    From table1 t1
    Left join table1 t2 on t2.idqu=t1.id
    Where t1.idqu=0
    Group by t1.id
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62392/3)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try:

```
SELECT question, SUM(CASE WHEN idqu > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY question
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select idqu, count(idqu) as reply_count
from   table_name
where  idqu <> 0
group by idqu
```

Comment: You wont get questions with zero answers with that query.

Answer (score 0):

This is for every replies, with a bit of php. You don't need group by I think.

```
$query="SELECT * From YourTable WHERE idqu>0";
$res=mysql_query($query);
mysql_num_rows($res);
```

If you want to select replies on one question, add an AND idqu=(yourInt) in the query.

Hope I did understand and replied correctly!